# Using a MySQL users table in subversion

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, svn, webdav

I'm currently starting to work for the first time on setting up a small ubuntu server that has mysql and subversion. I have never set up a server before and I am doing it for a professor. Currently I am using "password-db = passwd" option to have access to the repository via the svn:// protocol with svnserve being automatically stated up in /etc/init.d/rc.local , however I am also running some other applications (PureFTP) which already uses a MySQL table with md5 passwords. I have done a reasearch on the internet to check whether the same table could be used by svn as well to save time (and to avoid clear passwords on the passwd file), however most solution rely on using WebDAV in apache in conjuction with svn. However I would like to use the svn protocol that is provided by svnserve.

Is this possible? Do I have to use WebDAV? Is there a well written tutorial that I could follow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

External authentication for the svn:// protocol (i.e. svnserve) is handled by an extension called SASL, which has options for authenticating using a SQL statement.

See http://asyd.net/docs/cyrus-options.html and http://www.rhyous.com/2009/11/10/how-to-configure-subversion-to-use-cyrus-sasl2-authentication-to-authenticate-to-a-mysql-database/ for more details...